# Let $a_n\in A$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n-a_{n+1}|=0$,then which is true?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n\in A$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n-a_{n+1}|=0$,then which is true?

$1.$There exists $a\in A$ such that $a=\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$

$2.$There exists $b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $b=\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$

$3.a_n$ is bounded.

My attempt:For first option I have counter example $A=(0,1)$ and $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$

About second and third option I have no idea.But I have some observations may be this will be helpful

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n-a_{n+1}|=0$

So  $\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n-a_{n+1})=0$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for (3), take $a_n=\log n$, so $a_n-a_{n+1}=\log\frac{n}{n+1}$...

Comment: This is also counter example for 2nd option.

Answer (score 0):

neither is true, consider for example the sequence

$$a_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}.$$

However, (2) and (3) will be true, if

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty,m\rightarrow\infty}|a_n-a_m|=0,$$

this is the definition of Cauchy sequence.